# Identify this two-terminal SMD electronic component 16C95A

Tags: pcb, resistors

Please if anybody can identify this electronic part as it is burnt and I need to replace it. Your help will be so much appreciated!

Electrical interface RS-485, 2-wire. Supply voltage [V] 12 - 27 VDC.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Electrical interface RS-485, 2-wire. Supply voltage [V] 12 - 27 VDC.

Comment: I've put the comment information into your question where it belongs and edited the title to be much more specific (and useful to others searching the site).

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the Vishay (General semi) marking I'd say 1.5SMC16CA.
[Datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.vishay.com/docs/88303/15smc.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiss-SxkrXuAhVL8uAKHVIyA9kQFjADegQICxAB&usg=AOvVaw22cD-BkagaCwLjiThWyQ2V&cshid=1611511036211)